# question mark and colon - if else in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ternary-operator

Hi I have a question about ruby on rails

Apparently I have a statement like this:

```
def sort_column
    Product.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "name"
end
```

From what I read, it's said that this method sort the column based on params[:sort] and if there no params the products will be sorted by "name". However, I don't understand the way this statement is written, especially the second "?". Can someone explain it to me ?

Comment: Thank you, I found this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:

Comment: I gotta say, I quite like how Ruby allows me to daisy chain everything, though it does look weird to see a do-end block where the end has a method attached to it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is your code, rearranged for easier understanding.

```
def sort_column
  cond = Product.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) 
  cond ? params[:sort] : "name"
  #  it's equivalent to this
  # if cond
  #   params[:sort]
  # else
  #   'name'
  # end
end
```

First question mark is part of a method name, the second one - part of ternary operator (which you should read about).

Answer (score 11):

[`?:` is a ternary operator](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a) that is present in many languages. It has the following syntax:

```
expression ? value_if_true : value_if_false
```

In Ruby, it is a shorter version of this:

```
if expression
  value_if_true
else
  value_if_false
end
```

Comment: More importantly, it's a short version of this: `if expression then value_if_true else value_if_false end`. IOW: you can write an `if`-expression on one line, if you want to, you don't need to use the horribly cryptic unreadable conditional operator.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, +1 for inline `if`-`else`. Makes for very readable code, and really shines when compared to stuff like `question? ? true : false`. I always use it unless the line gets _too_ long.

Answer (score 4):

That line translates roughly as:

```
if Product.column_names.include?(params[:sort])
    params[:sort]
else
    "name"
end
```

The ? : is a ternary operator; shorthand for a brief if-else.

Comment: It's less a shorthand than a workaround for C and other languages where `if` is a statement and not an expression. Technically there's no reason to have it in Ruby, as shown by Python and Lua.

Answer (score 2):

```
Product.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "name"
```

The first question mark is part of the method name: `include?`.

The second question mark and the colon are part of the ternary operand:
    `(if this is true) ? (do this) : (else, do that).`

It means that, if `Product.column_names` contains `params[:sort]`, it will return `params[:sort]`. Else, it will return `"name"`.

Answer (score 0):

We must to be careful with the expression part to be evaluated in the ternary operator, for instance when using `and` versus `&&`, this is what could happen:

```
2.6.2 :014 > a = false
 => false
2.6.2 :015 > b = true
 => true
2.6.2 :016 > a and b ? 'first' : 'second'
 => false
2.6.2 :017 > a && b ? 'first' : 'second'
 => "second"
2.6.2 :018 > (a and b) ? 'first' : 'second'
 => "second"
```