# Emebedded Ruby: Short If Statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, embedded-ruby

I'm currently learning ruby but I cant get my embedded ruby to work proberly and help would be appreciated.

I'm basically trying to write the short version of this if statement in my embedded ruby

```
<% entity.attributes.each do |key, value| %>
  <%= if key == "name"
        link_to @entity, edit_entity_path(entity)
      else 
        value
      end %>
<%= end %>
```

According to my understanding (and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191247/question-mark-and-colon-if-else-in-ruby)) it should be as able to write it like this

```
<% entity.attributes.each do |key, value| %>
  <%= key == "name" ? link_to @entity, edit_entity_path(entity) : value %>
<%= end %>
```

This doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

> **Ralils Error Message:** 
>   syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting
>   keyword_do or '{' or '(' ...ey == "name") ? ...

Thx in advance for your help

Comment: When using ternary operator in Ruby your `if : else`'s must each be wrapped in parenthesis or if passing functions inside them they need to use the `function(args)` form and not white space (with exception of `+-/*` etc). For instance `true ? true.is_a? TrueClass : false` raises an error but `true ? true.is_a?(TrueClass) : false` does not. If you're returning with a ternary operator you can do it like `assertion ? (return something) : (return something_else)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a [link_to_if](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to_if) helper, which refactors your code to this:

```
<% entity.attributes.each do |key, value| %>
  <%= link_to_if key == "name", value, edit_entity_path(entity) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to wrap the arguments to `link_to` in parentheses:

```
<%= key == "name" ? link_to(@entity, edit_entity_path(entity)) : value %>
```